# A strengthening of Dirichlet prime number theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Dirichlet Theorem on arithmetic progression states that the sequence $\{a+kd\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ contains infinitely many primes when $(a,d)=1$. In other words if we let $A=\{a+kd\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and  $P$ is the set of primes then $|A \cap P|=\infty$. My question is about a subset of this sequence. Let $B=\{a+kd \in A \ | \ k\in P,\ a+d\equiv 1 \!\!\! \mod 2 \}$. Is it still true that $|B \cap P|=\infty$? If not, what sort of condition / refinement  would assure that such a subset has infinite cardinality without compromising the condition $k\in P$?

Comment: The answer is no, as for $a,d$ odd, $a+kd$ is even for all $2\neq k\in P$. Excluding this case, this is an open problem for all $a,d$.

Comment: See [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture).

Comment: A more appropriate title would be: a strengthening of Dirichlet's prime number theorem. (Special case means a weaker statement. A special case of a theorem is still a theorem, not an unsolved problem.)